# Impersonate user while creating Organization Service Proxy with XRM Tooling Connector

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-365

I am connecting to CRM Online v9.0 using XRM Tooling Connector.

I am trying to update a Contact using WebAPI. Once the contact is updated, the a workflow is triggered that sends an Email to the Contact. However I am getting - User does not have privilege send as. When I check in the Code, CallerID for service object is set to {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}. I think this is the reason why  my workflow does not execute successfully.

Can someone please help me with this.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: i used the below: Guid myId = ((WhoAmIResponse)service.Execute(new WhoAmIRequest())).UserId;

                        crmSvc.OrganizationServiceProxy.CallerId = myId; to set the caller ID. however I still get User does have send as privilege.

Comment: Update your question with your code please

Comment: The Xrm Tooling Connector and WebAPI are different ways to access Dynamics 365. Xrm Tooling Connector uses an instance of the CrmServiceClient while WebAPI requires an HTTP Request. Posting your code would help us get to the bottom of this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a Security issue. There are specific security privileges required to **act on behalf of** or **send emails on behalf** of other users.

These privileges are on the `Business Management` tab in the Security Role.

[image: CRM Roles]

In addition to this, the impersonated user must have also authorised emails to be sent on their behalf.

This setting is located in the the impersonated users personal settings

[image: Authorise Send]